# MS Report Builder Pareto Chart Unable to sort Categories

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I am attempting to build a industry standard pareto chart in MS Report Builder. The chart below is a generic example of what I want to see. The problem is that my categories are not ordered by the transaction_sum for that category, but by the name of the category. If I go to CategoryGroups Collection and specify that the sort expression be based on the transaction_amount field and click OK and run the report chart, it is ordered alphabetically on category. I go back into CategoryGroups Collection and the custom expression is gone and it has reverted to the category. I have found no solution to this issue.
So I thought I would go into the query for the dataset and add a new field ModCat consisting of a single character prepended to the category field i.e. 'ARent', 'BFood', CUtilities', 'DGym', 'ESmall_expense'. I use that as category in my chart and it sorts based one the transaction_sum! Excellent, but I still need to strip that ordering letter from the category labels. So I write a LabelsFormat expression for the vertical category axis that uses MID to remove that first letter. But when I run the report the 'ordering' letter is still there.  If I just use the original category field for the LabelsFormat it just ignores it. Am I missing something here? Is it really that hard to create a simple pareto chart in Report Builder? Any inputs are much appreciated. Thank you

[image]

Comment: Am I the only person that seems to have this issue??

Comment: This post which pretty much illustrates the same issue as mine has gone unanswered on community.powerbi.com: https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Sorting-column-chart-in-Report-Builder-not-working/td-p/1419167